# how to keep a button disabled in html even after refreshing the browser

Tags: html

I used the following code to create two buttons which are connected. One is enabled when the other is disabled and vice versa. Now the problem is that when I refresh the browser page the buttons revert to their original state, I want them to stay in the current state only even when I refresh the page and should change state only on button press manually.How can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('start').disabled=true;document.getElementById('stop').disabled=false;" type="submit" class="positive" name="start" id="start">start</button>

<button onclick="this.disabled=true;document.getElementById('start').disabled=false;" type="submit" class="negative" name="stop" id="stop">Stop</button>
```

I have an idea that by using session cookies i can do it but I have no knowledge of how to access them.

Comment: Have a look at local storage: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Answer (score -1):

Simply use the disable attribute of button

```
<button onclick="this.disabled=true;document.getElementById('start').disabled=false;" type="submit" class="negative" name="stop" id="stop" disabled>Stop</button>
```

**EDIT**:

I gave you an idea about how to do it. i.e. to set the disabled property of your button. 
It is upto you when you wish to disable it i.e. on server or on client and based on what condition.

In case you want to set it on server, you'll have to send the currently selected button to server via an [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) call and set session on the server (you haven't mentioned any server side scripting language otherwise I would have shown you code to set session)

In case you want to set it on the client side, you can use [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or [localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)(based on your target browser) and use it to get the previuosly selected button on screen load.

**EDIT2**

To use session in PHP, use the following code

```
function changeButtonState(id) {
    document.getElementById('start').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('stop').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            //success
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "saveState.php?button=" + id, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

HTML

```
    <?php 
   $id=$ _SESSION[ 'buttonId']; 
   if(strcmp ( $id , "start" )) 
   { 
    <button onclick="changeButtonState('start')" type="submit" class="positive" name="start" id="start">start</button>
    <button onclick="changeButtonState('stop')" type="submit" class="negative" name="stop" id="stop" disabled>Stop</button>
   }
   else
   {
    <button onclick="changeButtonState('start')" type="submit" class="positive" name="start" id="start" disabled>start</button>
    <button onclick="changeButtonState('stop')" type="submit" class="negative" name="stop" id="stop">Stop</button>
   } 
?>
```

PHP code for `saveState.php`

```
<?php 
   $id=$_GET[ "button"]; 
   $_SESSION[ 'buttonId']=$ id; 
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are always disabling a certain button on load. This is probably not what the OP wants, he will want to disable the button that was last clicked before the refresh.

Comment: @UmairP this does not solve my problem it permanently disables a button at startup thats it.
I need to retain what ever button was clicked irrespective of the button.

Comment: Thanks for updating @UmairP im using php so how do i do this I know nothing of ajax